# Guard gem: run some code at startup or shutdown?

Tags: ruby, guard

Is there a way to run some code at startup or shutdown of the [Guard gem?](https://github.com/guard/guard)?

I'd like to execute some maintenance tasks automatically when starting or ending a development session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this: http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/06/15/a-guardfile-for-redis/

Basically you can create an "Inline" Guard in your guardfile something like:

```
require 'guard/compat/plugin'

# the double-colons below are *required* for inline Guards!!!
module ::Guard
  class MyPlugin < Plugin
    def start
      puts "Starting server"
    end

    # Called when `stop|quit|exit|s|q|e + enter` is pressed (when Guard quits).
    #
    # @raise [:task_has_failed] when stop has failed
    # @return [Object] the task result
    #
    def stop
      puts "Stopping server"
    end

    # Called when `reload|r|z + enter` is pressed.
    # This method should be mainly used for "reload" (really!) actions like reloading passenger/spork/bundler/...
    #
    # @raise [:task_has_failed] when reload has failed
    # @return [Object] the task result
    #
    def reload
      stop
      start
    end
  end
end

# Startup the inline plugin
guard('my-plugin')


... other Guard config follows ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but where would you put this? I tried putting it into `config/initializers/my_guard.rb` of my Rails app, but then the server throws an error: `undefined method `guard' for main:Object (NoMethodError)`.

Comment: Just put it at the top of your Guardfile in the root of the project